# CSS framework with no Javascript

Tags: php, html, css, web, css-frameworks

I need to built a website but I have specific instructions to not use javascript. In addition to that I also have to make one that work for iPhone/mobile devices (also no javascript). It's fine for me to switch style sheets base on devices with some PHP magic, so it doesn't have to be the same CSS file.

What I want to know is, what are some recommended CSS frameworks for either or both scenarios?

Comment: Does Bootstrap sans the Javascript plugins require Javascript? Blueprint? 960.gs? SASS compiled by the server also would not require JS. This question is too abstract to answer, as well (what does JS have to do with CSS per se?). Welcome to SO.

Comment: http://thesquaregrid.com/, http://goldengridsystem.com/, http://cssgrid.net/, http://fluidbaselinegrid.com/

Comment: You can perfectly use Bootstrap without the JS part. Also check out Zurb's Foundation and Thoughtbot's Bourbon Neat, which relies heavily on SASS mixins (a good thing in my book).

Comment: Thanks for everybody's help. I was under the impression that bootstrap was reliant on the javascript, I guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use media queries to achieve this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries

The basic idea is to design from mobile up, or "responsive" design. You should google search that for more insight.

You then use such operators as

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
    #content{
        display:block;
    }
}
```

for example, to define how a particular element changes for each view.
There are tons of resources for this that can be found with basic searches, so the need to outline in detail here is none.

You can also add in specific style sheets like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-width: 480px)" href="http://foo.bar.com/stylesheet.css" />
```

if you want to separate the style sheets for each view.

good luck.

If you have specific questions, feel free to ask and I can update.

Comment: +1 for media queries if you're looking to build a mobile-friendly website. It's easy, and it works like a charm :)

Comment: lol. typically +1 actually comes with an upvote... unless I was downvoted first.

Comment: Haha, it's funny this competition for upvotes in this community! It does encourage for quality answers though I must admit. I just voted you up Kai, sorry I'm not quite used to voting yet!

Comment: The competition for upvotes is strangely psychological. It gives us nothing except some abstract satisfaction or self edification. Aside that though, it actually does help the OP (original poster) and any future readers who may have similar problems gravitate to the most sane suggestion, so it's not entirely selfish. Welcome to SO.

Comment: May I just add an example, just to clarify for our friend, a link to the mozilla website http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/. If you look at that page, and resize your browser, you will see that the layout changes as it narrows down. This is achieved with @media queries.

Comment: @Dyn - [It's called *gamification* and was intentional.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/10/the-gamification.html)

Comment: @jared - indeed. It really does help with the long, repetitive and horribly boring days drilling out meaningless client based websites. To be fair though, participation in SO really does teach you a lot and may actually help people become better programmers. I've learned many things since registering here.

Comment: Yes... [also intentional](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/02/how-to-write-without-writing.html). `:)` What's unusual is how *effective* it all turned out to be.

Comment: Of course, and it does work. When my questions or answers are voted down I'm like "whaaaat", and it pushes me to rephrase better and show code examples the time after that, ask and answer with a quality-oriented mind. Quite NOT surprisingly, there are no trolls and teenager questions in this community, and I think we owe it to the voting system :)

Comment: Oh there are troll and teenager questions. They get voted closed very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

As [**Kai Qing**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/461186/kai-qing) pointed out, media queries are really all you need to fill the criteria you mentioned.

If you want to use a CSS framework to make things easier for you, you could use [**Bootstrap**](http://getbootstrap.com/), [**Foundation**](http://foundation.zurb.com/) or any other framework out there, without the JavaScript part.

[**Here**](http://jslegers.github.io/responsiveness/)'s a demo of how you could implement a [**responsive design**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) with [**Cascade Framework**](http://jslegers.github.io/cascadeframework/). The demo does not use any JavaScript code and falls back to the desktop version for IE6 to IE8 (as these browsers do not support media queries).